# Please explain the working of earthing wire and humanbody in this case

Tags: electrostatics

I am sitting on the floor. And I am ironing my clothes, suppose something goes wrong and live wire comes in direct contact with the metal body of my iron. While at the same time I am also in direct contact with the body of iron ( which is now having charges due to live wire ). So will the current flow through my body and then into the earth, or will it flow from earth wire that is connected to it ? Please explain with reason.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer to your question is yes - if this situation were to happen, and your body were well grounded, yes electricity would flow through you and you would get shocked.  The shock would be extremely painful and possibly lethal.

Now I'd say that as long as your iron is in good repair, there's no real need to be afraid of this happening.  Most irons made in the last 40 years or so have many safety features inside to prevent this from happening.

I haven't disassembled any pressing irons lately to know what these safety features are specifically.  But the household appliance industry in general is rather overrun with safety features to prevent things like this, and I'm sure that pressing irons are made the same way.

Lastly, at the end of your question you state:

> . . . So will the current wire flow through my body and then into the
>   earth, or will it flow from earth wire that is connected to it.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this, but I think the answer is that the electricity will flow into the earth.  By the way, the wire carrying the high voltage is referred to as "hot", and the wire that "returns" electricity to the power company is "neutral", at least in Texas electrician lingo.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou so much...Well I just needed it for my physics studies....Otherwise my iron is perfectly alright :)

Comment: And the piece of text that you quoted...actually that was a mistake...Thanks for pointing out. I have corrected it by editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

The Earth wire connected to the metal body of the iron is a safety feature.
If the live wire touches the metal case a large current flows though the live wire and the Earth wire as it is a very low resistance path.
The large current either causes a fuse to melt or a circuit breaker to trip.
Either way the live wire becomes disconnected from the metal case.

If at the same time you are touching the metal case of the iron very little current will flow though you as you will present a much higher resistance path to Earth than the earth wire.
This will mean that you probably not feel a thing.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your contact with earth.

You will only be harmed if a large current can flow through your body. Small currents, even at very high voltage, will not hurt you, although the shock may be unpleasant. Anything over 100 mA may be lethal, over 200 mA will cause burns.

However, current can only flow if there is a complete circuit through your body. Such a circuit will exist if you touch both wires of the power cord. That is likely to kill you.

In your example you are touching only 1 wire, and relying on the return path through earth to complete the circuit. If you are standing on a dry carpet, you may well not feel anything, or no more than a tingle. This is because the carpet presents a very high resistance to the current, so only a very small current can flow. If, on the other hand, you are standing on bare feet in a puddle of water, you may well be killed, as there is only a very small resistance to earth, and a large current will flow. This happened to me once - it's not recommended, and I still have burn scars on my fingers.